# Can't refresh packages in Update Manager

Tags: update-manager

In Update Manager I try to update the list of packages and I get a
window titled synaptic with the following output

---

Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring-security/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1360:8c01::18 80]

(many more lines like this)

Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.

---

How do I fix this?  Please answer with complete step by step instructions.
Thanks.

Comment: Upgrade to latest version here is the link http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/upgrade

Answer (score 0):

If you go to [the URL listed](http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring-security/main/binary-amd64/Packages) you'll find there's no page there.

There's a reason for this is that Raring was the first release to have security updates for 9 months. It has reached end of life. You can read more [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ReleaseEndOfLife).

Long story short, it's time to upgrade to newer version (14.04).